# I have problem in routing of quasar framework of vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

Here is my code here whatever route i give it takes me to the home page only . When I give path auth it takes me to the home can anyone explain me why , and clear my doubt ..

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: () => import("layouts/MainLayout.vue"),
    props: true,
    children: [
      {
        path: "auth",
        name: "auth",
        component:  () => import("pages/AuthPage.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "",
        name: "home",
        component: () => import("pages/HomePage.vue"),
        
      },
    ],
  },
  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)*",
    component: () => import("pages/ErrorNotFound.vue"),
  },
];
```

export default routes;

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a snippet how you route to the pages? If you are using named routes, you have to call them with a router-link component:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">home</router-link>
```

Or in javascript:

```
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { username: 'erina' } })
```

Example: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/named-routes/app.js

If you want to do it a bit simpler remove the "name" from the path and do a simple `router.push('/home')`.

Comment: Since I have just testing it with just giving the path in the browser . When I hit the "/auth" path it just takes me to the home page

Comment: Hard to say with just the route definitions. I created a blank quasar project and it works for me with your routes. Can you share the content of the App.vue and the MainLayout?

Comment: Here is the MainLayout.vue